# Passing variables and object to start-job

Tags: powershell, scope, arguments

I know that a script block executed via start-job cannot see the variables outside of the script block. To pass variables in you use the -arguments paramater. So why does this work (from MS article):

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Name $args } -ArgumentList "powershell"
```

But this does not:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-aduser $args } -ArgumentList "samaccountname"
```

When I run it and receive the job I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert 'samaccountname' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
```

This same syntax works though outside of running it via start-job:

```
Get-aduser "samaccountname"
```

This last command is to demonstrate to you that the syntax is correct in the start-job script block. So why does the command expect an `ADUser` object when executed via start-job wheras outside of the script block it will accept a string?

I need to be able to execute the command via start-job

Comment: I can only image that it's due to you passing it an array, or more specifically a value of type `system.object[]` when using `-ArgumentList`. When running `Get-ADUser` and not *explicitly* specifying the parameter, it defaults to the [Parameter Set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets?view=powershell-7.1) that uses `-Identity` as the *positional* parameter 0. This is important because, `-Identity` only accepts 4 type of values: *DistinguishedName*, *GUID (Object Guid)*, *Security Identifier*, and *SAM Account Name*. So...

Comment: "*The cmdlet searches the default naming context or partition to find the object. If two or more objects are found, the cmdlet returns a non-terminating error.*". Which explains the not so odd behavior due to you passing a non expected value to it.

Comment: So, *type-constraining* the argument passed by `-ArgumentList` in the scriptblock, `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { [string]$ar = $args; Get-aduser $ar } -ArgumentList "samaccountname"` or, using the [Remote Variable of `$using:somevariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1):`$string = 'samaccountname'; Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-aduser $using:string }`, should work.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala you should totally post that as an answer, `$args.GetType()` should be enough to understand the error and also `$args[0]` would give the expected result.

Comment: I thought it was due to passing an array so I tried what Santiago said before I posted it here. It looked like it didn't work at the time but I just tried it again now and it works, so it must have been due to another error I didn't read properly. Feel free to post that as the answer Abraham and I will accept it. thanks guys. I have another question now, I'll post that next (there were two parts to this!)

Comment: Hey guys,if you would be so kind, here is my follow up question to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554807/powershell-passing-objects-to-to-start-job

Answer (score 0):

All credit here goes to Abraham in the comments above. He provided the answer but for whatever reason didn't submit it as an answer, so I am providing this to help others.

The issue is that `-Arguments` is always an array, even if you only provide one value. In my example where it didn't work with the second command (the `get-Aduser` one) is because I was passing an array to a paramater which expected a string. Changing the code to `args[0]` fixed this.

The first command worked because it's paramater accepts a string *or* an array.

NOTE: Passing complex **objects** to `Start-job` is a different story and has it's own issues, I posed this as a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554807/powershell-passing-objects-to-to-start-job)